# How to Insert data in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my dotnet core project i need to insert data in elastic search. I am using bellow code for insert.

```
List<Patient> employeeData = null;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5001/api/Employee/GetAll");
request.Method = "GET";
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
      Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
      var data= reader.ReadToEnd();
      reader.Close();
      dataStream.Close();
      employeeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employee>>(data);
}
  var lst = employeeData;
  int count = 0;
  foreach (var obj in lst)
  {
         count ++;
         this.client.Index(obj, i => i
         .Index("employee")
         .Type("myEmployee")
         .Id(count)
          // .Refresh()
      );
}
```

After Execute the above code i am using bellow url for check the inserted data

`localhost:9200/emp`

I am getting following output.

```
{"emp":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"myEmpl":{"properties":{"firstName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"gEmailId":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"gMobile":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"wmployeeID":{"type":"long"},"registrationNo":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1547020635852","number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"6kle4jzMQDSICnPsmATbDw","version":{"created":"6050499"},"provided_name":"emp"}}}}
```

I am not able to see any of my data. What is the problem in this.

Comment: What is the output of `localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`

Comment: Can you debug and also read what is in the Index function response

Comment: Thanks  ben5556. I am getting following response.  yellow open   emp           6kle4jzMQDSICnPsmATbDw   5   1         10            0     35.5kb         35.5kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost:9200/emp` returns the settings and mappings for index 'emp'. For the content, try `localhost:9200/emp/_search`.